Bazel remote caching to s3 returning (Remote Cache: 403 Forbidden)
So I have a project that is built in go lang and I use bazel to build it and I wanted to make some changes to this in certain way that instead of building it each it I want to store the cache and when I'm building again from my machine or any other machine (team), remote machine I want bazel to get these cache files and then build on top of it and when there are new changes I they will be synced to s3 bucket. I followed few article from bazel, few git repo's , but I came to this. Any suggestions
I'm using some aws credentials and I am able to get details like s3 buckets, push object to the same bucket but the credentials bazel is using are not able to do that caching
set up credentials on the environment and then used this command
bazel build //my-app --remote_cache=https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name --remote_upload_local_results --remote_default_exec_properties=aws_profile=default

